# Socket is not working (without any error message)

Tags: java, sockets

i am just programming a multiplayer java game and i tried to write a server. But every time i start it, It simply dosen't work and eclipse is not even giving me an error message. I found out that the error must be at this line: Socket sock = serverSock.accept(); Can anyone see the mistake?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Frame {

JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;
JButton start;
JLabel status;



public Frame() {

    frame = new JFrame("Server");
    panel = new JPanel();
    start = new JButton("Start");
    status = new JLabel("Server is not running.");

    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



        try {

            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
            Socket sock = serverSock.accept();
            InputStreamReader isReader = new    InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        status.setText("Server is running.");
        status.setForeground(Color.green);
        start.setText("Stop");




    }});

    status.setForeground(Color.RED);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(150,100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(start);
    panel.add(status);

}

}
```

Thanks
Lennart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One source of error here is the fact that you're blocking the `EDT`. Swing is single-threaded so any process heavy or blocking calls, such as `ServerSocket#accept()`, will *freeze* your UI. Here you could use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) instead.

Also when you do implement `SwingWorker`, you will need to *use* your `BufferedReader` to read data from the client. Currently no client data is being displayed.

Comment: oh i down't think it is because of the swing components. i already tried the server without a gui and the same happened.

Comment: serverSock.accept() will block until a connection is made. Did you connect to the server? Also, in the code nothing will be visible as you don't display anything from the client using your `BufferedReader`